# Can't make confluence run on port 80 with Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, port, windows-server-2012-r2, confluence

I am trying to get Confluence to run on port 80 using Windows Server 2012 R2. It's not working even after reinstalling it on port 8090. But the default works great locally.
`netstat -abn` yields nothing running on port 80. Any ideas on what to try?

Comment: What user are you running confluence as?

Comment: the only user on the system who has administrator rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something to run on port 80, it's usually better to use port forwarding to handle relaying port 80 to it's standard port.

Port 80 is a "reserved port" as well as a "low port."

Many programs will refuse to run on it unless they have proper permissions, which you likely don't want to give them.

Instead, once you have Confluence working on it's default port again, simply use the firewall software to relay port 80 to the default port of Confluence.  This is a much safer, saner, and more flexible solution that generally works with all software.

Occasionally you may have to change a configuration or two to make sure it's various security mechanisms don't refuse connections where the client is accessing it through port 80, and it is receiving it on it's default port.  Some security mechanisms against XSS vulnerabilities and Monkey in the Middle attacks tend to occasionally false alarm on port-relays, much like they do for NAT.   However, when doing this you can always connect to it through it's default port, and thus you have access to it and know it's working even if you can't connect through port 80, which is very good for diagnostics.

Comment: and the fact that I am running as administrator I take it confirms that confluence wont run on port 80? Do you happen to know what extra permissions I could give confluence to get it to run on port 80? otherwisre I think I will have to do the process you described.

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the listen ports in your server.xml?
Check this out:
[Change listen port for Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Change+listen+port+for+Confluence)

Comment: yes and when you install the software you can pick the port which is what I did.

Comment: Did you checked the server.xml after installation?